# A code generator task in a multi-project gradle build

Tags: gradle

I have studied thousand similar questions on SO and I am still lost. I have a simple multiproject build:

```
rootProject.name = 'mwe'
include ":Generator"
include ":projectB"
include ":projectC"
```

with a top level `build.gradle` as follows (`settings.gradle`):

```
plugins { id "java" } 
allprojects { repositories { jcenter() } }
```

and with two kinds of project build.gradle files.  The first one (`Generator`) exposes a run command that runs the generator taking the command line argument:

```
plugins { 
  id "application" 
  id "scala"
}

dependencies { compile "org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.12.3" }
mainClassName = "Main"
ext { cmdlineargs = "" }
run { args cmdlineargs }
```

The code generator is to be called from projectB (and an analogous projectC, and many others). I am trying to do this as follows (projectB/build.gradle):

```
task TEST {
  project (":Generator").ext.cmdlineargs = "Hurray!"
  println ("Value set:" + project(":Generator").ext.cmdlineargs )
  dependsOn (":Generator:run")
}
```

Whatever I try to do (a gradle newbie here) I am not getting what I need.  I have two problems:

- The property `cmdlineargs` is not set at the point that task `:projectB:TEST` is run.  The `println` sees the right value but the argument passed to the executed main method is the one configured in `Generator/build.gradle`, not the one in `projectB/build.gradle`. As pointed out in responses this can be work around using lazy property evaluation, but this does not solve the second problem.
- The generator is only run once, even if I build both `projectB` and `projectC`. I need to run `Generator:run` for each of `projectB` and `projectC`  separately (to generate different sources for each dependent project).

How can I get this to work? I suppose a completely different strategy is needed.  I don't have to use command line and run; I can also try to run the main class of the generator more directly and pass arguments to it, but I do find the run task quite convenient (the complex classpath is set up automatically, etc.). The generator is a Java/Scala project itself that is compiled within the same multi-project build.

Comment: the problem is that your are setting the `args` property of `run` task (in project A) and setting the `cmdlineargs` ext property value (in project B) during the **Configuration phase**... and in your case, project A is evaluated/configured before project B : that's why when project B is configured, the `ext { cmdlineargs = "" }` block resets the property value to ""

Comment: Thanks! Oh. This helps, but forcing a different ordering will not really work then. Ultimately,  I will have many projects like B, each with a different `cmdlineargs`.  So what is the pattern to handle that?

Comment: you could use Gradle lazy property evaluation feature, I'll provide an answer with example of code

Comment: Thanks. This is a nifty trick and looks quite elegant. The semantics is not the one that I need though.  So if I have two projects depending on projectA:run and want to build both, the "run" action will be executed only one, with the lazily resolved value for whatever happened to be set last (I think).  I need the dependency to be "cloned" for every projectX depending on projectA - so I obtain multiple tasks.  How to do that?

Comment: This is not how gradle should work. One project should not be able to set another's variables like this. I think this is an [x/y problem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)... please explain what you are trying to achieve and you will likely get a better solution

Comment: I have deleted my answer because your question was hiding some other requirements (invocation of Code generator project from several other projects), and the solution I proposed does not suite this scenario as you understood. Like @lance-java said, you should rephrase the question, I'm sure you will get some solution to implement your use case in a better and Gradle way...

Comment: Thanks. I have reworked the question another time, making the generation aspect explicit.

Answer (score 2):

Note: tasks aren't like methods in java. A task will execute either 0 or 1 times per gradle invocation. A task will never execute twice (or more) in a single Gradle invocation

I think you want two or more tasks. Eg:

```
task run1(type:xxx) {
    args 'foo'
}
task run2(type:xxx) {
    args 'bar'
}
```

Then you can depend on run1 or run2 in your other projects.

Comment: In addition, you should not use an extra project just for a single task. Instead you should create a task type in a *buildSrc* project or even in an external plugin and then create a task of this type in each of the projects.

Comment: lance-java Yes, this is what I want to achieve.  Just I want to avoid inserting a dependency from the Generator to the other project.  Logically there is no dependency.  So as @lukaskörfer writes these tasks should be created for each client project locally. I will read up about buildSrc and creating plugins (although it does sound extremely excessive for something that is  a main use case of a build system: creating and consuming files).

Comment: You can declare these tasks wherever you like (same project or separate project)

Comment: I get that, although I would like to stay DRY, so the reusable part of the task should be specified only once.  This is why I was trying to depend on a task, but parameterized dependencies don't seem to be supported.